# How to aggregate/partition window data by dynamic group?

Tags: postgresql

A question like this may have already been asked & answered, but I'm having trouble finding anything (it's tough to know what exactly to search for / how to phrase this).

If I have a table of values by date:

```
select *
from (values
  (date '2018-05-11', 'lorem'),
  (date '2018-05-10', 'ipsum'),
  (date '2018-05-07', 'dolor'),
  (date '2018-05-05', 'hello'),
  (date '2018-05-04', 'world'),
  (date '2018-04-30', 'foo'),
  (date '2018-04-15', 'bar')
) as v(date, name)
order by date desc
```

How can I aggregate the values by date groups (e.g. "5 days") — grouping dynamically by the first value onwards (e.g. May 11-7, 6-1, Apr 30-26, etc.), *not* statically (e.g. modulo 5 days)?

Desired result:

```
min_date   | max_date   | names
-----------+------------+--------------------
2018-05-07 | 2018-05-11 | lorem, ipsum, dolor
2018-05-04 | 2018-05-05 | hello, world
2018-04-30 | 2018-04-30 | foo
2018-04-15 | 2018-04-15 | bar
```

————

I believe I need to first derive the max date to group each row under, which would be , e.g. `2018-05-11`, `2018-05-05`, etc.

I've tried two conceptual approaches for doing that, but neither work.

———

The first approach is to build up this rolling max date, but this isn't valid (`column "groupbydate" does not exist`):

```
select *,
  case
    when date > (lag(groupByDate) over w) - interval '5 days' then (lag(groupByDate) over w)
    else date
  end as groupByDate
from input
window w as (order by date desc)
```

————

The second approach is to "find" the max/"group by" for each row, but I'm not sure how to differentiate the current *table* row's `date` from the current *window* row's `date:

```
select *,
  max(date) filter (where date < input.date + interval '5 days') over w
from input
window w as (order by date desc)
```

I think I can implement the second approach using a subquery, but I'm curious: is it possible to achieve this using window functions? Thank you!

***EDIT: The second approach is wrong.** It can find a different "group by" date for different dates that should be in the same group.*

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT: Actually, this is wrong!** This can find a different "group by" date for different dates that should be in the same group.*

Here's how I achieved this with a subquery:

```
select date, name, (
  select max(date)
  from input as i2
  where date < input.date + interval '5 days'
) as date_group
from input
```

And plugging into this outer query gets me my desired results:

```
select min_date, max_date, names
from (
  select date_group, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date, string_agg(name, ', ') as names
  from groups -- results of above query, e.g. using CTE
  group by date_group
  order by date_group desc
) as x
```

Still curious if there's a way to do this with windowing functions. Thanks!